# Pause splash screen until user responds to permission request in android app

Tags: android, android-permissions, splash-screen

in my android application i have a splash screen that lasts 5 seconds during those 5 seconds i ask the user to grant location permission , I want to pause the splash screen activity until the user grants or denies the permission request.If the activity is not paused until the user responds, the next activity will be activated without having the user's response about the permission request here's my code

SpalshScreen activity:

```
public class SplashScreen extends BaseActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT = 6000;

    some properties ....


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //hide the title bar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

       // This is the method that asks the user for permission
        locationPermGranted = CheckLocationPermission();


        deviceLanguage = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
        DeviceLanguageCode = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName() + ".prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        codeIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, PhoneVerification.class);
        myIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ProfileSettings.class);
        loggedIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Main.class);
        notLoggedIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (!locationPermGranted) {

                    killApp();
                }

                if (sharedPreferences.getString("userLanguage", DeviceLanguageCode) == null) {
                    editor.apply();
                }

                if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isRegistered", false)) {


                    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isPhoneVerified", false)) {


                        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false)) {
                            // GO TO HOME

                            startActivity(loggedIntent);
                        } else {
                            // GO TO LOGIN
                            editor.apply();
                            startActivity(notLoggedIntent);
                        }

                    } else {
                        editor.apply();
                        startActivity(codeIntent);
                    }
                } else {
                    //GO TO PROFILE SETTINGS
                    editor.apply();
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }

                finish();

            }
        }, SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT);

    }
```

Comment: what if you put all code of handler inside an if(locationPermGranted) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permission up front and if the permission is already granted, continue your `Handler()` and if not, then request for the permission and handle the result. Here's how:

1. Put all your Handler() code in a function so you can call it easily:

   ```
   private void continueOperation(){
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {

               if (sharedPreferences.getString("userLanguage", DeviceLanguageCode) == null) {
                   editor.apply();
               }

               if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isRegistered", false)) {


                   if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isPhoneVerified", false)) {


                       if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false)) {
                           // GO TO HOME

                           startActivity(loggedIntent);
                       } else {
                           // GO TO LOGIN
                           editor.apply();
                           startActivity(notLoggedIntent);
                       }

                   } else {
                       editor.apply();
                       startActivity(codeIntent);
                   }
               } else {
                   //GO TO PROFILE SETTINGS
                   editor.apply();
                   startActivity(myIntent);
               }

               finish();

           }
       }, SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME_OUT);
   }
   ```

   Here, you don't have to check for permission because this function will only be called 
   with granted permission.
2. Then, put a permission check in `onCreate()`:

   ```
   if (!locationPermGranted)
       killApp();
   else
       continueOperation();
   ```
3. Now, handle the `onRequestPermissionResult()` and call `continueOperation()` if permission is granted.

   In case, you don't want the user to wait for 6 seconds if the permission is granted in `onRequestPermissionResult()` which would obviously be bad UX, you can use the `Handler()` in the `else{}` of 2nd point. So, User will only have to wait if the permission was previously granted which is the basic purpose of a SplashScreen.

Answer (score 1):

Surround `newHandler().postDelayed` method with if-else statement. If the user grants permission then only run the post delay method.